# Toggling wifi on and off trips local geofences in iOS7

Tags: ios, ios7, cllocationmanager, clregion

My app is monitoring around a dozen circular regions at a time.  Region monitoring works as expected most of the time.  However, I have noticed that often when I toggle wifi on and off from the settings or control center,

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region
```

is called for all regions, regardless of size, within several miles of a my current location.

Anyone know why this might happen, and if there is a way to filter out these false positives?

Comment: location services use wifi in part until slower GPS can be determined.  Without wifi at all, the accuracy radius will remain quite high for 15+ seconds until GPS can be determined solo.  It may be that turning off wifi expands the accuracy radius temporarily, tripping off nearby zones.

Comment: I have tested this with Apple's Reminder app with identical results.  It'd be awesome if someone has found a method to filter out inaccurate region-monitoring results or to suspend region monitoring for a few seconds after wifi has been switched on.

Comment: How have you solved this problem?

Comment: You could check the `CLLocationManager`'s horizontalAccuracy value of its `location` property and filter out anything above a certain value.